# Does Flutter expose SkMatrix::setPolyToPoly like Android does?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Is there a similar function of the Android class

```
android.graphics.Matrix.setPolyToPoly
```

in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Dart doesn't expose this at its core, and Flutter engine doesn't surface many of the Matrix operations from `SkMatrix` (which is where Android goes to for this method).

It should be entirely possible to implement in dart (probably in cooperation with the [`vector_math`](https://github.com/google/vector_math.dart/blob/master/lib/src/vector_math_64/matrix4.dart) library.  The implementation isn't entirely trivial though, and I don't have a good set of test cases for it.